# using push (like Laravel echo) to activate browser tab

Tags: laravel, browser, notifications, echo, push

While the user is working in an other browser tab or window, would it be possible to activate the browser  where a front-end Javascript (like Laravel Echo) is running and receiving a push notification? -

Could be annoying but also very helpful as an alert!

Comment: "Could be annoying" tends to mean "browsers have taken action against it already". This used to be abused to lock people into a tab for those "your computer has a virus" malware pages. It's no longer possible in most browsers.

Comment: agreed and what I thought, just gathering opinions ;-)